# Count a specific character like a in a string and give it out

Tags: c, string, count, character

Hi i am new in coding and i just want to know how i can count a specific character like 'l' in a string and after the counting i just want to give the result out.

Trying to learn more about coding in C for doing some researches for school.
I just want to create some diagrams with the % of a specific character in a word like:

- hello <- our string
- l     <- our specific character

result: 2 l in this "hello" string.

Now some of my thinking, cause people shouldnt think i didnt do anything.

- read string
- splitt characters like h/e/l/l/o
- maybe now a loop to get the amount of the "l" ?
- if "l" is found -> count+1
- printf for the amount of l's

I would be really happy if someone could help me.

Comment: That doesn't really mean he shouldn't write it for learning purposes.  That said, OP should try it and ask a specific question.  Voting to close.

Answer (score 4):

Your algorithm is fine; do you need help with transforming your pseudocode into actual C code? If so, here you are, with an overwhelming amount of comments:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char mystr[128]; // a char array, where the string will be input
    char ch; // the char we want to count
    char *p; // loop variable
    unsigned cnt; // number of occurrences

    fgets(mystr, sizeof(mystr), stdin); // read the string - max 128 characters, beware!
    ch = fgetc(stdin); // read the character
    cnt = 0;

    for (p = mystr; *p; p++) {
        if (*p == ch) cnt++; // walk through the string, increase the count if found
    }

    printf("%u occurrences found\n", cnt);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is working great!
Yes i tried to transform my preudocode into c code, but failed.

Comment: @user1959263 And have you understood it as well?

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't use the for loop end condition of *p as there's risk of memory overrun if the null terminator doesn't exist.

Comment: @Darcy `fgets()` always NUL-terminates.

Comment: @H2CO3 Assuming the person reading the example is aware of that...  And then doesn't use the same end condition method while building/fetching the string using a different method  ;)  Pefectly valid though  :)

Answer (score 0):

In C a `String` is an array of type `char`. You can iterate over the array and compare `char` by `char` with your own.

Comment: Yes this was one of my mistakes which i have done. Thank you so much sir !